# how to get percentage from two mysql column while some values are 0 and sort by max

Tags: mysql

I am working on a php website and in a mysql query I need help , I have teams playing games, I want to sort teams by winning percentage max on top, her eis another issue some columns has 0 value .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwNX9.png)

here is the query I am trying

```
SELECT TeamID,Wins,Losses,ConferenceWins,ConferenceLosses, 
        (ConferenceWins+ConferenceLosses)/ConferenceWins AS avg_points 
FROM teamse_tbl","SeasonID='2022' ORDER BY avg_points DESC, Wins DESC
```

Comment: First sort the obvious issues with your query out.

Comment: It would also be useful to know what you want to compute. In other words: What do your columns stand for? For instance, what is the difference between "conference" and "overall"?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Overall means total games played and conference means games played with same region teams

Comment: And what do you want to compute?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I want to sort it by winning percentage in confrenece , like team A wins 4 and loses 2 , so winning percentage is 50%, Team B Wins 2 and loses 0, so here percentage is 100%, so team B should be on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image does not match the query. You should always include the table definition and sample data.

To calculate the winning percentage based in your query structure you can do:

```
select 
  TeamID, 
  sum(ConferenceWins)/sum(ConferenceWins+ConferenceLosses)*100 as "Win%"
from teamse_tbl
group by TeamID
order by `Win%` desc;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b9eLYm1pHbB91YeGWuBKcP/1)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it didn't worked as it should you may see in screenshot as team B has einning  precentage 100% https://prnt.sc/tUZZKsrWmoZa

Comment: https://prnt.sc/lpTtRLhz5Jg2

Comment: here is the complete query 

SELECT TeamID, Wins, Losses, ConferenceWins, ConferenceLosses, sum(ConferenceWins)/sum(ConferenceWins+ConferenceLosses)*100 as 'Win%' FROM teamse_tbl WHERE SeasonID='2022' group by TeamID order by 'Win%' desc

Comment: As said, you should provide the table description with sample data. Do not use images.

Comment: Thanks its clear to me now , just one question , should not we have wins percentage in minus if team wins =0 and loses =2 , its due to 0 values in wins i think https://prnt.sc/tFX58IH9UhKx

Comment: If a team has lost all the games, the win% is zero. There is no such things as negative win%.